# Is forking possible w/ InnoDB & unique records?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am considering moving my MyISAM table to InnoDB. I have a lot of tables w/ columns set to unique values and I use perl. If I switch to InnoDB (and thus take advantage of row-level locking rather than table-level locking) and use forking, will I encounter problems with duplicate entries? (ie, since I will be inserting many rows simultaneously into the table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have `UNIQUE` indexes in place, no rows violating these constraints will be allowed.

You might however run into some concurrency issues when doing inserts within transactions. If two duplicating rows are inserted in two different, concurrent transactions, one of them will fail to commit.

Answer (score 0):

Uniqueness can be achieved by creating unique indexes. In this case DB engine takes care of it. Also, a proper use of transactions helps you to avoid concurrency issues.